# Is there a way to start an Airflow worker with a stable IP address on GKE?

Tags: airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Airflow on GKE and I need to access a SFTP server. This server is protected with an IP whitelisting. The thing is, everytime a worker starts, a new pod is created along with a new IP address.

Does anybody know how to assign a static outgoing ip to the cluster/workers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cloud NAT mapping.

Then all the outgoing connections from GKE will be automatically NAT-ed with the outgoing IP of the gateway.

You can read more about it here:

Cloud NAT (https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview)

You can have stable egrees IP there.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. 
Thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot. The real issue here was that didn't know enough about networking in Google Cloud. It took me a while but everything works as intended now !